# Is it possible to change windows phone theme styles (eg: PhoneTextNormalStyle)

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

Is it possible to change [PhoneTextNormalStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769552(v=vs.105).aspx) from code behind ? I tried in ways but no luck.

I have already used this style in many places in my app . Now i want to change foreground color . How can i do this without changing all the places in xaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom style on your App.xaml based on the PhoneTextNormalStyle and just adapt the Foreground to suit your needs:

```
<Style x:Key="RedPhoneTextNormalStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

Then adapting the current style calls to the new one should be fairly easy (search & replace)

```
<TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" 
                   Text="APP NAME" 
                   Style="{StaticResource RedPhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
```

The advantage of using a custom style is that you can always extend it if you need to add more functionality to it, as well as use it as a base for other styles